# .NET Localization Failures

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, localization, cultureinfo

I am currently writing a .NET 4 app in C# and WPF.

I'm including localization for 15 languages. This basically involves creating a bunch of resources, creating several instances of CultureInfo, and assigning them to Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture and Thread.CurrentThread.CurrenUICulture. For each I seed the two-character neutral culture code (e.g. "en" for English), and then I call to .CreateSpecificCulture before assigning each instance of CultureInfo.

I am testing my app on Windows XP, Windows Vista, Windows 7 and Windows 8. All 15 languages work as expected on all versions of Windows, except for four specific languages on Windows XP. Instead of the expected resourced characters (like the ones that I get with Vista, 7 and 8), in Windows XP all I see are "square" or "block" looking characters for ko (Korean), ja (Japanese), zh-CHS (Chinese - Simplified) and zh-CHT (Chinese - Traditional).

I have googled this several times. This does not seem to be a problem anyone else has had before???

Any ideas on what is causing this, and how I can fix it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [Install the East Asian Language Files](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/int_pr_install_languages.mspx?mfr=true).

From above link:

> On the Languages tab, under Supplemental language support, select the Install files for East Asian languages check box.

And

> The East Asian languages include Chinese, Japanese, and Korean. The files for most other languages are installed on your computer automatically by Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Normally this languages are not installed, so most likely there are no fonts that include the characters.

Go to "Regional settings" and check if fonts are installed.